# How to do bit-wise zero-filling right shift in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, math

According to [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/s48/0.57/manual/s48manual_37.html), `arithmetic-shift` will bit-shift left and right. The right shift preserves the sign. Is there any unsigned right-shift operator, which fills the vacated bits with zero instead of the sign bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift it right by 1 bit, then zero out the sign bit. Then shift it by however many extra bits you need.